# Show multiple row as one row SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a following query.

[image]

My result after executing is this.

[image]

But issue is in here for invoice no 'I261001001S000371' there is 2 records. I want to show as 1 record. Means for that invoice cash amount and cheque amount should show in 1 row.

Any ideas please?

Comment: To show it in one row you would need to come up with some logic to show where the  amount is coming from.  are invoices only paid with cash/cheque/credit or is there more ways? Or if you dont want a breakdown just remove the cash/cheque/credit columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query: Use aggrigate function to sum up all the cash that are common for all the invoice no. I am not sure about the settle. You can use aggrigate, IF needed.

```
SELECT InVoiceNo, sum(cash), sum(cheque), 
     sum(credit), NetAmount, Settle
from
  (--Your select query to get result as specified in question) as a
group by InVoiceNo, NetAmount, Settle
```

Comment: You should not `SUM(NetAmount)`. Your result will be correct because your have it in the `GROUP BY`, but it is counter productive to `SUM` something that is in the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

Change your select statement to `SUM` the `Cash` and `Cheque` and `Credit` columns `GROUP BY InvoiceNo, NetAmount, Settle`

That way each invoice will show the total of each of the columns that you specify in your Case statements and get it all in one line

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Over`-clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) with a CTE to sum them up per `InvoiceNo`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT InvoiceNo, NetAmount, Settle, Credit,
          RN =  ROW_NUMBER()   OVER ( PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ORDER BY InvoiceNo ),
          Cash =   SUM(CASH)   OVER ( PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ),
          Cheque = SUM(Cheque) OVER ( PARTITION BY InvoiceNo ),
          Credit = SUM(Credit) OVER ( PARTITION BY InvoiceNo )
   FROM dbo.InvoiceHeader -- ... and other tables ...
)
SELECT InvoiceNo, NetAmount, Settle, Cash, Cheque, Credit
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @Matt: but credit was not mentioned: _"for that invoice cash amount and cheque amount shold show in 1 row"_. However, i think OP understands the logic.

Comment: i know but you can bet it will be needed ;)

Comment: @Matt: mission completed ;)